# Disable an option of Script

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to disable the option to generate a database script from SSMS? From Right click on a DB >> Task >> Generate scripts..

Thanks,

Comment: I don't believe so. Even if there were... what are you trying to SOLVE? I can just as easily create the scripts using SMO through powershell should that option be disabled.

Comment: It is likely some Windows group policy could be devised, for corporate environments. Not enough information in the question, however. Please edit to say what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to disable the General scripts feature for all the users except sa. However, I realized that it is not possible. Thanks to all of you! Sean and Michael.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option to disable the generate scripts function. This option comes with the ability to VIEW DEFINTION. What level of access does the user have? What do they really need to do?